# Is there a way to loop through a list of variables in Postman body?

Tags: jenkins, automation, postman, newman

So I have this API that changes the phone number on an account. The problem is, when it comes to automating my API requests it fails since it is replacing the phone number with the same thing every time.

Is there a way I could get my Postman to iterate through a list of phone numbers, add to the body and stop when a 200 response is made?

Thanks

[image: I want to change the phone number in the body]

Comment: show the code sample, data sample, error stack trace, we are not super humans to understand it by imagination. Please read [mcve] and follow it everytime

Comment: I have added a picture of the API body I want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Postman provides two features to achieve this:
- **Tests**: tests are written in JavaScript and executed after receiving a response. You can use them to check the response code and if required, execute the same test [again](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/branching-and-looping/). Some sample scripts to test the response and set the body for next request is provided [here](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test-scripts/).
- **Variables**: you can define and use [variables](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments-and-globals/variables/) in your tests

You might also check: [iterations](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection-runs/running-multiple-iterations/) and [data files](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection-runs/working-with-data-files/)